# How to import all files except JS, CSS, HTML as assets in Webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-loader

I know that I can import assets (e.g. images) in my JS code using Webpack. This is useful to include hash of the file in it's name, so I can cache the assets forever using HTTP

```js
import cat from './cat.png'

export function CatGallery() {
    return <img src={cat} alt="A wonderful cat" />
}
```

```js
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  output: {
      assetModuleFilename: '[name].[contenthash][ext]',
  },

  module: 
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.png$/,
          type: 'asset/resource'
        },
      ],
  }
};
```

What is unfortunate is that I have to explicitly list every extension my assets can have in `test` regex. Is there a way to write a regex that will cover all files except ones related to CSS, JS and HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your configuration using a regex that matches the ones *except* listed in the group. This regex uses a construct called [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) - (?!a)

```js
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  output: {
      assetModuleFilename: '[name].[contenthash][ext]',
  },

  module: 
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(?!(css|html|js|ts|jsx|tsx)$)[^.]+$/,
          type: 'asset/resource'
        },
      ],
  }
};
```

Explanation:

```
/
\. # match dot (escaped)
(?! # not followed by
    (css|html|js|ts|jsx|tsx) # any of these extensions
    $ # that are in the end. Prevents false matches like .ts.png 
)
[^.]+$ # the previous group didn't consume any input - we're still in place after dot. 
# The extension itself doesn't contain dots and must be at least one character, 
# and also should be the last in the filename
/
```